# Group By Query and Non-Group By Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query with a Group and Non-Group By.. However, I intend to retrieve and use both of them, without duplicating the query (one of them used Group By, and one of them not used Group By), as it would impact the performance.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT [People].[FirstName], [People].[LastName], [People].[Age], [People].[RegisterDate], [PeopleGroup].[FirstName] AS PGFirstName, [PeopleGroup].[LastName] AS PGLastName, [PeopleGroup].[Age] AS PGAge
FROM [Game]
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Age], [RegisterDate] FROM [People]
WHERE [Age] < 20 AND [RegisterDate] BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND GETDATE()
) AS People
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Age] FROM [People] AS PeopleGroup
WHERE [Age] < 20 AND [RegisterDate] BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY [FirstName], [LastName], [Age]
) PeopleGroup
```

The above query is repetitive as I have select something from the same table twice, what makes it different is only the criteria and the second query is using the `group by` clause.

Any suggestions on how to improve the above query?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to create a Cartesian product of your data to every distinct row in your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively what you have is the same as this, however, what you're aiming for seems odd. Why do have duplicate people in your database, for example?

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [FirstName],
           [LastName],
           [Age],
           [RegisterDate]
    FROM [People]
    WHERE [Age] < 20
      AND [RegisterDate] BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND GETDATE())
SELECT [FirstName],
       [LastName],
       [Age],
       [RegisterDate]
FROM CTE C1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT
                         [Firstname],
                         [LastName]
                         [Age]
                  FROM CTE) C2;
```

Comment: ah that's right, I could use `CTE` to achieve something like I wanted it to. How clueless I am. Thanks for pointing that out :).